# Is .NET PInvoke available on Linux and Mac OS X platforms?

Tags: c#, .net, linux, macos, pinvoke

Platform Invokation in .NET Framework available on Windows.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern MessageBoxResult MessageBox(IntPtr hWnd, String text, String caption, int options);
```

Is PInvoke available on Linux and Mac OS X platforms? for example for Mono project?

If Linux and Mac OS X supported PInvoke, Can you give me some example or references in your answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Interop with Native Libraries** 
 http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries

Comment: In short: Yes, Linux and MacOS X do support P/Invoke. However, calling into Windows-specific libraries like "user32.dll" is not supported, because Linux and MacOS X are not Windows.